# How to stop a sound when certain other sound is inserted in the mix in ffmpeg?

Tags: android, audio, ffmpeg, android-ffmpeg

I'm using a ffmpeg command that takes a set of sounds, mixes them into a single file, separating them by certain time intervals.

Below is how my command is today.

```
ffmpeg -i 
close_hh.wav    -i \
crash_l.wav     -i \
crash_r.wav     -i \
floor.wav       -i \
kick_l.wav      -i \
kick_r.wav      -i \
open_hh.wav     -i \
ride.wav        -i \
snare.wav       -i \
splash.wav      -i \
tom_1.wav       -i \
tom_2.wav       -i \
  tom_3.wav  -filter_complex  " [6]adelay=0|0[note_0];  [0]adelay=360|360[note_1];  [6]adelay=1260|1260[note_2];  [0]adelay=1537|1537[note_3];  [6]adelay=2494|2494[note_4];  [5]adelay=2767|2767[note_5];  [0]adelay=2969|2969[note_6];  [6]adelay=3673|3673[note_7];  [5]adelay=3924|3924[note_8];  [0]adelay=4132|4132[note_9];  [0][note_0][note_1][note_2][note_3][note_4][note_5][note_6][note_7][note_8][note_9]amix=inputs=11:normalize=0" record.wav
```

This is the resulting audio that this command generates:

**ffmpg record.wav:** https://drive.google.com/file/d/1LFV4ImLKLnRCqZRhZ7OqZy4Ecq5fwT3j/view?usp=sharing

The purpose is to generate a drum recording, so I would like to simulate the dynamics of the hi-hat sounds: **When the closed hi-hat is played, the open hi-hat will stop playing immediately if it is still sounding. The same behavior does not happen for any of the other sounds.**

One point that makes this a little more challenging is that other sounds can also be played between open hi-hat and closed hi-hat strikes, and theoretically the sound interruption behavior should work normally.

Below is a recording demonstrating the expected result. (My app already reproduces the sound result I need internally, so I just made a simple recording with the microphone to illustrate)

**mic record.wav** https://drive.google.com/file/d/19x19Fd_URQVo-MMCmGEHIC1SjaQbpWrh/view?usp=sharing

Notice that in the first audio (ffmpeg record.wav) the first sound (open hi-hat) continues playing after the second is played.
In the second audio (mic record.wav) the first sound stops immediately after the second sound is played.

How should the ffmpeg command be to get the expected result?

Comment: Off the top of the head `atrim` is the most trivial filter to use. You may be able to use `sidechaincompress` if you don't need to kill the volume 100%. Finally, `acrossfade` may work the best. Study the filter documentation, starting from tgese. There are a ton of effects available.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply. I studied the acrossfade, but I still don't understand how its syntax would be applied to the command I already have...
In my command each note can be represented with an entry of " [6]adelay=1260|1260[note_2];" for example. Where should I place the acrossfade to get the desired effect?
Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

While I'm not sure FFmpeg is the correct tool to synthesize music, here is a couple ways to approach your goal. First, I suggest to "compose" one instrument (in the case of a drumset, one drum/cymbal) at a time as illustrated below and then mix full tracks of instruments together.

Now, let's take the first 3 hi-hat segments to show how you can construct a filtergraph to form a hi-hat track.

(1) Trim each file to the length and concatenate all streams:

```
[0]atrim=duration=0.36[note_0]; \
[6]atrim=duration=0.9[note_1]; \
[0]atrim=duration=0.277[note_2]; \
[note_0][note_1][note_2]concat=3:0:1[aout]
```

While this works, if there is any audible sound at the trimmed moment, you'll likely hear the abrupt cut-off of the sound. This brings the alternate...

(2) Trim each file to the length + extra and cross-fade:

Let's say 10 ms overlap suffices, then you want to elongate each segment by 10 ms (0.01 s).

```
[0]atrim=duration=0.37[note_0]; \
[6]atrim=duration=0.91[note_1]; \
[0]atrim=duration=0.277[note_2]; \ # last file remain same length
[note_0][note_1]acrossfade=d=0.01:c1=exp:c2=exp[notes_01] \
[note_01][note_2]acrossfade=d=0.01:c1=exp:c2=exp[notes_012]
```

This will get ridiculously long, so you can shorten a bit by

```
[0]atrim=duration=0.37[note_0]; \
[6]atrim=duration=0.91,[note_0]acrossfade=d=0.01:c1=exp:c2=exp[notes_01]; \
[0]atrim=duration=0.277,[note_01]acrossfade=d=0.01:c1=exp:c2=exp[notes_012];
```

The `c1` and `c2` are the fading curve profiles. [See this Wiki page for the available fade curves](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/AfadeCurves).

Finally, I arbitrarily chose 10 ms, and it is likely too short, so experiment and pick the best overlap duration.

Comment: Many thanks for the reply! I'll try to fit it into the command I currently have, but I'm not very good with the ffmpeg syntax, I'll probably need to go back and ask you for help :P

Comment: Just out of curiosity, you said that you don't consider ffmpeg the correct tool to synthesize music, what would be a better solution for my application? To contextualize, I have some drum samples in hand, when the user activates the recording mode I just save the pieces he pressed and the distance in milliseconds between each hit. As a final step I run the command with ffmpeg to generate an audio file. If I knew a better/easier way to do this that would be great.

Comment: You need to specify your dev environment, but assuming it's react.js or a javascript type, my quick search ended with [tone.js](https://tonejs.github.io/) and [this example of theirs](https://tonejs.github.io/examples/sampler) seems to match your application well. [Here](https://github.com/Tonejs/Tone.js) is their github repo. It appears that you need to understand [WebAudio API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API/Using_Web_Audio_API) to fully utilize it. So, it may not be fast and trivial but I think it'll pay off down the road.

Comment: Sorry I didn't mention it earlier. In fact, my development environment is basically native Android, so the solution need be written in Kotlin or Java. Today I use the [ffmpeg-kit](https://github.com/tanersener/ffmpeg-kit) to use ffmpeg on Android. Could you suggest me some other way to achieve the result?

Comment: Java comes with native support for MIDI, so I'd start from there [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/MIDI-synth.html) [link2](https://cs.longwood.edu/java/docs/technotes/guides/sound/programmer_guide/chapter1.html) [link3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/accessing.html). Essentially, search for terms like 'midi' 'synthesizer' 'sampler' 'sound capture'. good luck